# Max Sample Value (sound file) python

Tags: python-3.x, audio

I am trying to write a code to determine the minimum, maximum, and total zero values for a .wav file.  The output should return something like

```
Largest Sample Value is:xxxx
Smallest Sample Value is:xxxx
There are x amount of 0's in sample.
```

I am having trouble determining if using the max() for the .wav sample is the right thing to do after using a for loop.

```
f=pickAFile()
sound=makeSound(f)
for i in range(0,getLength(sound)):
  value=getSampleValueAt(sound,i)
print max(value)
print min(value)
```

Not sure how to find the zero values within it either.  I can use the print function to output the smallest and largest statement however I cannot figure out the min/max to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repetition of [Max() function using python from loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550848/max-function-using-python-from-loop/25550952#25550952):

```
def largest():
    f = pickAFile()
    sound = makeSound(f)
    value = [getSampleValueAt(sound, i) for i in range(1, getLength(sound))]
    print max(value)
    print min(value)
    print value.count(0)
```

Also, as you tagged the question as python-3.x, the print statements should be `print(max(values))`