# Max() function using python from loop

Tags: python, max, audio

I am trying to write a program to determine the maximum value of a sample from a sound.  The loop returns the values of all the samples, however I cannot figure out how to print the largest.

```
def largest():
f=pickAFile()
sound=makeSound(f)
for i in range(1,getLength(sound)):
  value=getSampleValueAt(sound,i)
print max([value])
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
def largest():
    f = pickAFile()
    sound = makeSound(f)
    value = []
    for i in range(1, getLength(sound)):
      value.append(getSampleValueAt(sound, i))
    print max(value)
```

Or

```
def largest():
    f = pickAFile()
    sound = makeSound(f)
    print max(getSampleValueAt(sound, i) for i in range(1, getLength(sound)))
```

With your code, `value` is overwritten at each iteration. If you make a list with all the values, you can then find the max using `max`.

Also see:

- [How to find min/max values from rows and columns in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854859/how-to-find-min-max-values-from-rows-and-columns-in-python)
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

Comment: This works, although I am also trying to count the occurrence of "0" in the sample now which is retrieving a thread death.  Is value.count("0") a viable why to do it?

Comment: It should be, but isn't the values integers, so you would need `value.count(0)`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't remember we are dealing with audio data. With possibly *millions* of samples. If you want to stick with something *efficient* both in space and time, you have to rely on the far less sexy:

```
def largest():
    f = pickAFile()
    sound = makeSound(f)
    max = getSampleValueAt(sound, 1) # FIX ME: exception (?) if no data
    idx = 2
    while idx < getLength(sound):
        v = getSampleValueAt(sound, i)
        if v > max:
            max = v
        i += 1

    print max
```

Generator-based solution are efficient too in term of space, but for speed, nothing could beat a plain-old imperative loop in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it but maybe:

```
def largest():
 f=pickAFile()
 sound=makeSound(f)
 value = [ getSampleValueAt(sound,i) for i in range(1,getLength(sound)) ]
 print max(value)
```

Comment: And what if you have several Msamples?

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux well then I would have to change it but this should be the fix to the code provided with the topic